# Creating a Google Line Chart using a passed JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, datetime, google-visualization

I have a JSON array passed via ajax and am having issues charting the data.
I need to be able to pass the array to the chart dynamically adding columns without duplicates.

I've tried passing different values using `arrayToDataTable()` and `DataTable()` then using the `data.addColumns()` and `data.addRow()` however each time errors.

ajax call fired:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/file.php",
    data: {
        data: dataHere,
    },
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(result) {
        var div = mydiv;
        drawInterfaceChart(result,div);
    },
});
```

JSON encoded from PHP using:

```
$SQL = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, 'new Date(%Y, %c, %d, %H, %i, %s)') as date, ifDesc, ifInOctets FROM tablename WHERE date between (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) and CURDATE()";
$Results = mysqli_query($db, $SQL) or die("Mysql cannot run Query");
$SQLRows = mysqli_num_rows($Results);
if ($SQLRows > 0) {
    $rows = array();
    while ($row = MySQLi_fetch_assoc($Results)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
}
```

Example of a passed JSON array:

```
0: {date: "new Date(2019, 3, 26, 16, 13, 15)", ifDesc: "lo", ifInOctets: "2147483647"}
1: {date: "new Date(2019, 3, 26, 16, 13, 15)", ifDesc: "Port1", ifInOctets: "2147483647"}
2: {date: "new Date(2019, 3, 26, 16, 13, 15)", ifDesc: "Port2", ifInOctets: "2147483647"}
3: {date: "new Date(2019, 3, 26, 16, 13, 16)", ifDesc: "Port6", ifInOctets: "2147483647"}
4: {date: "new Date(2019, 3, 26, 16, 13, 16)", ifDesc: "imq0", ifInOctets: "906413834"}
5: {date: "new Date(2019, 3, 26, 16, 17, 31)", ifDesc: "lo", ifInOctets: "2147483647"}
6: {date: "new Date(2019, 3, 26, 16, 17, 49)", ifDesc: "Port1", ifInOctets: "2147483647"}
7: {date: "new Date(2019, 3, 26, 16, 17, 53)", ifDesc: "Port2", ifInOctets: "171330279"}
8: {date: "new Date(2019, 3, 26, 16, 17, 57)", ifDesc: "Port6", ifInOctets: "2147483647"}
9: {date: "new Date(2019, 3, 26, 16, 17, 57)", ifDesc: "imq0", ifInOctets: "1103910085"}
10: {date: "new Date(2019, 3, 26, 16, 20, 38)", ifDesc: "lo", ifInOctets: "2147483647"}
11: {date: "new Date(2019, 3, 26, 16, 20, 39)", ifDesc: "Port1", ifInOctets: "2147483647"}
12: {date: "new Date(2019, 3, 26, 16, 20, 40)", ifDesc: "Port2", ifInOctets: "194386054"}
13: {date: "new Date(2019, 3, 26, 16, 20, 41)", ifDesc: "Port6", ifInOctets: "2147483647"}
14: {date: "new Date(2019, 3, 26, 16, 20, 42)", ifDesc: "imq0", ifInOctets: "1128562685"}
```

My draw chart function:

```
function drawInterfaceChart(array,divR) {
    var dataSet = [];
    $.each(array, function (data, value) {
        dataSet.push([value.date, value.ifDesc, value.ifInOctets]);
    });
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataSet);
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(divR));
    var options = {
        title: '',
        legend: { position: 'right' }
    };
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

This layout returns the error: Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string

Column 0 needs to be a datetime, and a line chart presented with each column and it's data per 'ifDesc' value. I am looking to add more data into the chart so creating the columns needs to be dynamic.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention my page does include: `google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'gauge']});` and I have other working charts on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few issues here, first the date.

you won't be able to get an actual datetime from this string --> `"new Date(2019, 3, 26, 16, 13, 15)"`
without using the `eval` method, which I wouldn't recommend.

on top of that, in javascript, when using this particular date constructor,
the month is zero based, meaning --> `January = 0`

as such, the above date would result as *April 26*, I'm thinking you want *March 26*.

here's proof (run the following snippet)...

```js
var testDate = eval("new Date(2019, 3, 26, 16, 13, 15)");
console.log(testDate);
```

recommend changing the format to --> `3/26/2019 16:13:15`
`{date: "3/26/2019 16:13:15", ifDesc: "lo", ifInOctets: "2147483647"}`
then convert to datetime in javascript --> `new Date(value.date)`

---

next, the chart expects each `ifDesc` to be in its own column in the data table,
as in the following structure...

```
['Date', 'lo', 'Port1', 'Port2', 'Port6', 'img0'],
[new Date('3/26/2019 16:13:15'), 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 906413834],
```

this will be difficult to build in the query, without hard-coding.

instead, we can use google's data view to create the structure needed.

pass the json via ajax in the following structure.

`{date: "3/26/2019 16:13:15", ifDesc: "lo", ifInOctets: "2147483647"}`

load the data table similar to what you have done,
we need to convert the date and parse the number...

```
var dataSet = [];
$.each(array, function (data, value) {
    dataSet.push([new Date(value.date), value.ifDesc, parseFloat(value.ifInOctets)]);
});
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataSet);
```

then use the following to create a data view for the line chart.
it first creates a column for each `ifDesc`.

```
var viewColumns = [0];
var distinctLabels = data.getDistinctValues(1);
$.each(distinctLabels, function (index, label) {
  viewColumns.push({
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      if (dt.getValue(row, 1) === label) {
        return dt.getValue(row, 2);
      }
      return null;
    },
    type: 'number',
    label: label
  });
});
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns(viewColumns);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var jsonData = [
    {date: "3/26/2019 16:13:15", ifDesc: "lo", ifInOctets: "2147483647"},
    {date: "3/26/2019 16:13:15", ifDesc: "Port1", ifInOctets: "2147483647"},
    {date: "3/26/2019 16:13:15", ifDesc: "Port2", ifInOctets: "2147483647"},
    {date: "3/26/2019 16:13:16", ifDesc: "Port6", ifInOctets: "2147483647"},
    {date: "3/26/2019 16:13:16", ifDesc: "imq0", ifInOctets: "906413834"},
    {date: "3/26/2019 16:17:31", ifDesc: "lo", ifInOctets: "2147483647"},
    {date: "3/26/2019 16:17:49", ifDesc: "Port1", ifInOctets: "2147483647"},
    {date: "3/26/2019 16:17:53", ifDesc: "Port2", ifInOctets: "171330279"},
    {date: "3/26/2019 16:17:57", ifDesc: "Port6", ifInOctets: "2147483647"},
    {date: "3/26/2019 16:17:57", ifDesc: "imq0", ifInOctets: "1103910085"},
    {date: "3/26/2019 16:20:38", ifDesc: "lo", ifInOctets: "2147483647"},
    {date: "3/26/2019 16:20:39", ifDesc: "Port1", ifInOctets: "2147483647"},
    {date: "3/26/2019 16:20:40", ifDesc: "Port2", ifInOctets: "194386054"},
    {date: "3/26/2019 16:20:41", ifDesc: "Port6", ifInOctets: "2147483647"},
    {date: "3/26/2019 16:20:42", ifDesc: "imq0", ifInOctets: "1128562685"}
  ];

  drawInterfaceChart(jsonData, 'chart_div');

  function drawInterfaceChart(array, divR) {
    var dataSet = [];
    $.each(array, function (data, value) {
      dataSet.push([new Date(value.date), value.ifDesc, parseFloat(value.ifInOctets)]);
    });
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataSet, true);

    var viewColumns = [0];
    var distinctLabels = data.getDistinctValues(1);
    $.each(distinctLabels, function (index, label) {
      viewColumns.push({
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          if (dt.getValue(row, 1) === label) {
            return dt.getValue(row, 2);
          }
          return null;
        },
        type: 'number',
        label: label
      });
    });
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns(viewColumns);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(divR));
    var options = {
      title: '',
      legend: {position: 'right'},
      interpolateNulls: true  // <-- add this option
    };
    chart.draw(view, options);  // <-- use view to draw chart
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Amazing work, Thank you so much for your very detailed answer - This works exactly how I needed